# Accept any of 2 possible keys in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have the following array,

```
orders: [
          {
            description: order.description,
            order_number: order.number,
            specifications: {
              size: order.size,
              weight: order.weight
            }
          } 
        ]
```

and in the specifications hash I would like to be able to accept `size` or `dimension` as keys, like instead of

```
specifications: {size: order.size, weight: order.weight}
```

do something like

```
specifications: {size || dimension: order.size, weight: order.weight}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What would you like to do if both `size` _and_ `dimension` keys are present?

Comment: I believe you expect from `Hash` datatype more than it can give you. In this situation you should define your own datatype (based on [`Struct`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Struct.html) maybe).

Answer (score 1):

A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values. Also called associative arrays, they are similar to Arrays, but where an Array uses integers as its index, a Hash allows you to use its keys.

IMHO, you cannot achieve the above-mentioned behavior

If you want to fetch value of either size or dimension you can try the following way.

```
irb(main):011:0> specifications = {size: 10, weight: 20}
=> {:size=>10, :weight=>20}
irb(main):012:0> order_spec = specifications[:size] || specifications[:dimension]
=> 10
irb(main):013:0> order_spec
=> 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The following does what you're after using [`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice) and [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

```
{
  orders: [
    {
      description: order.description,
      order_number: order.number,
      specifications: {
        weight: order.weight
      }.merge(order.slice(:size) || order.slice(:dimension))
    } 
  ]
}
```

E.G.

```
order = { size: 10 }
order.slice(:size) || order.slice(:dimension)
# => {:size=>10}

order = { dimension: 'med' }
order.slice(:size) || order.slice(:dimension)
# => {:dimension=>"med"}

order = { size: 10, dimension: 'med' }
order.slice(:size) || order.slice(:dimension)
# => {:size=>10}

order = { size: 10, dimension: 'med' }
#           vvv note the order of keys has been reversed
order.slice(:dimension) || order.slice(:size)
# => {:dimension=>"med"}
```

This does, however, feel a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): instead of trying to adjust the key, why not pass both and handle differently the other end?

```
response = {
  orders: [
    {
      description: order.description,
      order_number: order.number,
      specifications: {
        weight: order.weight,
        size: order.size,
        dimension: order.dimension
      }
    } 
  ]
}
```

And then:

```
order = response[:orders].first
size_spec = order.dig(:specifications, :size) || order.dig(:specifications, :dimension)
```

Hope this helps, let me know how you get on.

Comment: Did this help at all @CrescentStrike?